# Нужна библиотека для минификации HTML JS строк

Tags: javascript, html

Вводим в первый инпут обычный текст *HTML* или *JS*. Нужна библиотека на ***JS*** для их минификации **только на стороне клиента без обращения к серверу!**

```
let str = "<     button id="minified-button"   >Минифицировать< / button >";
function minifyHTML(str);
str >>минифицирован>> "<button id="minified-button" >Минифицировать</button>"
```

Comment: JS: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Comment: Не подходит, нужно что бы работало в браузере без обращения к серверу.

Comment: Мои поиски ни к чему не привели, но думаю регулярку написать не сложно. Главное знать все случае, где нужно будет сокращать код.

Comment: @MishaSaidov, для всех случаев регулярки не хватит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в качестве варианта:

```js
$("#before").val('<     button     id="minified-button"   >Минифицировать  < / button    >');

let minify = str => {
  str = str.replace(/[\t\n]/g, "");
  str = str.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ");
  str = str.replace(/[\t\n\s]*<[\t\n\s]*\/[\t\n\s]*/g, "</");
  str = str.replace(/[\t\n\s]*<[\t\n\s]*/g, "<");
  str = str.replace(/[\t\n\s]*>[\t\n\s]*/g, ">");
  return str;
}


$("#submit").on("click", () => {
  let after = minify($("#before").val());
  $("#after").val(after);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20%;
}

body>* {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

textarea {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="before"></textarea>
<button id="submit">Минифицировать</button>
<textarea id="after"></textarea>
```

Comment: только для очень простых случаев

Comment: Да, это на коленке написанный вариант в качестве примера. На деле он должен обрастать регулярками.